# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()Ljava/lang/String;

Tags: java, spring, cxf

I am building a web service using Java, Apache Cxf and Spring Frame work 
Build: Maven
Deployment: Tomcat 8.0.42
The servlet used in **web.xml** is of version 2.5. When I deployed the **WAR** into tomcat and start the server I am getting the following Error. I have tried many of the solutions presented in the stack but none seems to be working. I have checked for the servlet-api.jar in maven dependencies and it is not present either. Also gave the servlet version in web.xml as 3.0, but it also didn't seem to resolve the issue. Need good inputs.
Thanks in advance

```
    Apr 12, 2017 5:24:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/SAMPLE-WS]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:943)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/SAMPLE-WS]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsServerContainer.<init>(WsServerContainer.java:150)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsSci.init(WsSci.java:131)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsSci.onStartup(WsSci.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5303)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    ... 6 more
```

**web.xml**

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

    <display-name>SAMPLE-WS</display-name>

   <!--
        - Location of the XML file that defines the root application context.
        - Applied by ContextLoaderListener.
    -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/sample-cxf-beans.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <description>Apache CXF Endpoint</description>
        <display-name>cxf</display-name>
        <servlet-name>cxf</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>cxf</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
    </session-config>


</web-app>
```

**POM.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

      <groupId>com.javaws.sample.ws</groupId>
      <artifactId>SAMPLE-WS</artifactId>
      <packaging>war</packaging>
      <name>SAMPLE-WS</name>


     <properties>
        <project.wsdl.path>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/WSDLs/Sample_1.wsdl</project.wsdl.path>
        <target.wsdl.path>WEB-INF/WSDLs/Sample_1.wsdl</target.wsdl.path>

      </properties>
      <dependencies>
            <!-- Spring Web -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <!--  Apache CXF -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-simple</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
            </dependency>  
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-rt-bindings-soap</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
              <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty</artifactId>
           </dependency>


        </dependencies>


    </project>
```

Comment: You don't need dependency of `cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty` If you are deploying it on tomcat. Remove that and try again.

Answer (score 2):

the method `getVirtualServerName` has been added in ServletContext in Servlet 3.1.  Find the java doc's method [getVirtualServerName](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getVirtualServerName())

this problem can have at least 2 causes:

1. your servlet version is older that 3.1.
2. other jar has the servlet older version than 3.1

to solve it, you can try the below way.

I. to check your pom.xml whether there are the below code.

```
  <dependency>
       <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
       <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
       <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

if your pom.xml has the above code, it would still has that problem. you can do the second way.

II. to check your other jar has refer to the `javax.servlet-api` jar. for example, the `org.apache.santuario` has refer to the `javax.servlet-api` jar. the pom.xml:

```
<dependency>  
    <groupId>org.apache.santuario</groupId>  
    <artifactId>xmlsec</artifactId>  
    <version>1.4.3</version>   
</dependency>
```

but when you look at the maven dependencies, it refer to the `javax.servlet-api` jar whose version is 2.3 older than 3.1.

[image]

so you should exclude the 2.3 version. pom.xml:

```
<!-- exclude servlet-api 2.3 jar-->  
<dependency>  
    <groupId>org.apache.santuario</groupId>  
    <artifactId>xmlsec</artifactId>  
    <version>1.4.3</version>  
    <exclusions>  
        <exclusion>  
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>  
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>  
        </exclusion>  
    </exclusions>  
</dependency>  

<!-- servlet-api 3.1 version has getVirtualServerName() -->  
<dependency>  
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>  
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>  
    <version>3.1.0</version>  
</dependency>
```